# FindViewById returns null when using custom title in Android

Tags: android, tabactivity

I'm using a TabActivity with a custom image title. While calling

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);

if (resId > 0)
{
    ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
    im.setImageResource(resId);
}
```

'im' is null. Based on other questions I saw that not calling setContentView can cause this, but I'm not using any layout file. Is there something I'm missing?

this is my_custom_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView  android:src="@drawable/launch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/title_bar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: Can you post your layout file as well place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Rajath use  `setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_title);`

Comment: Praveen, I got the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Comment: I think you are extending the java class from TabActivity.Instead of that TabActivity extends that calss from Activity Rajath

Comment: I am extending from TabActivity. I don't understand the alternative that you mention. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: please extend your java file from Activity